# (Re)Share a mounted network volume on OS X

Tags: macos, network-shares

I have a network share with an archive on it. Only I have access to this share and cannot change the permissions. On OS X server I want to mount this share, then create a new share (from the server) of a folder on this mounted network volume so users can access part of this archive read-only, is this possible? Or do all shares have to be physical drives?